# Fetching Tweets on Wordpress Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter

I'm trying following script to fetch tweets on wordpress site :

```
'http://codepen.io/jasonmayes/pen/Ioype'
```

Its working on codepen but not on wordpress site. 
I want to show each tweet in separate div with Masonry layout.

Please suggest any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct ID?

There is a comment in the code that shows how to generate the ID that you have to use.

`/**
 * ### HOW TO CREATE A VALID ID TO USE: ###
 * Go to www.twitter.com and sign in as normal, go to your settings page.
 * Go to "Widgets" on the left hand side.
 * Create a new widget for what you need eg "user time line" or "search" etc.
 * Feel free to check "exclude replies" if you don't want replies in results.
 * Now go back to settings page, and then go back to widgets page and
 * you should see the widget you just created. Click edit.
 * Look at the URL in your web browser, you will see a long number like this:
 * 345735908357048478
 * Use this as your ID below instead!
 */`

Comment: Yeah... I'm using correct ID. Even tried that used ID in script. but its not working.